# Android:Json parsing fb graph api url

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api

In my app i am trying to retrieve the data from a fb graph api url as below

```
URL fbmsg = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+FbPostId()+"?access_token="+TOKEN+"");
            URLConnection yc = fbmsg.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            String s = "";

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

            System.out.println(inputLine);
            //Log.d(TAG, "getPostId trace getFbPostId " + inputLine);   
            s = s + inputLine + "n";
            //Log.d(TAG, "getPostId trace getFbPostId " + s);   
            in.close();
            //System.out.println(s);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(inputLine);
            //JSONObject message = json.getJSONObject("message");
           String fbmessage = json.getString("message");
            System.out.println( "message: " + fbmessage );
```

i am getting the output in json format but i am unable to read the message , getting error at this line `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(inputLine);`
getting nullpointer exception . below is my log

```
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894): getPostId
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894):    at org.appright.myneighborhood.utils.FBUtils.doInBackground(FBUtils.java:104)
01-28 14:05:56.384: E/FBUtils(5894):    at org.appright.myneighborhood.utils.FBUtils.doInBackground(FBUtils.java:1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html tutorial how we get data from webservice using URLConnection

Comment: Maybe it is because of your missing curly brackets? so only the `println` is executed inside the while, until inputLine is `null`.. therefore the `NullPointerException`

Comment: @prospeak  iam getting the json data in out put with System.out.println(inputLine); now iam unable to parse..

Comment: @teekib : but u are getting NullPointerException means you are not getting data from server and if getting it then make sure you are getting string which is convert-able to JSONObject or JSonArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use StringBuilder instead of String for reading data from InputStream and try as to read data from InputStream:

```
StringBuilder inputLine = new StringBuilder();
String s;
String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
   inputLine.append(s + NL);
}
in.close();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(inputLine.toString());
```